# How to execute SQL query stored in variable in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to run a query in PHP using `mysqli_query()`

My query is stored in variable `$query` as follows:

> ```
>   $query = "INSERT INTO spaces (";
>   $keys = '';
>     $values = '';
>     foreach ($newrow as $key=>$value){
>         $keys .= $key.",";
>         $values .= "'".$value."',";
>     }
>     $keys = substr($keys, 0, -1);
>     $values = substr($values, 0, -1);
>     $query .= $keys;
>     $query .= ") values(";
>     $query .= $values;
>     $query .= ")";`
> ```

On using `echo $query`, it shows the generated query.

However, I must now execute this query in the database.

Currently, I'm using `$result = mysqli_query($success, $query);` where `$result` is the variable for establishing connection to database.
 However, this isn't working and neither is `$result = mysqli_query($query);`

I need help in figuring out how to correctly pass a variable as query.

Comment: Do you have `mysqli_connect();` and `mysqli_select_db();` in your script?

Comment: Look at the [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) manual page then. It tells you which parameters are required where.

Comment: Melancholy, yes `mysqli_connect();` and `mysql_select_db();` are present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a link:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

Then:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
```

What is in your `$success` var? If it is the link, then are you checking:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    return false;  // or whatever other flag that it failed
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've done all the above. The database connection is made. In my code, $success is the same as your $link and I've used `mysqli_connect_errno()`

Comment: Use die($query); right before it executes. Grab the query off the screen. Using phpMyAdmin, or other database tool, execute the query directly in the database. From there you can begin to play with the query and see what is missing (e.g. type mismatch).

Comment: mseifert, I've done that. I echoed the query that was being generated and ran it independently in phpMyAdmin. It worked perfectly. My only error seems to be in figuring out how to pass a variable in `mysqli_query();`

Comment: The only requirements for passing variables for mysqli_query() are that the $link (your $success) be a valid link and the $query be a valid query. If you have pasted the exact query - from an echo or die()- into phpMyAdmin and it works, then the only other possibility is the connection. Test your connection with the query hard coded: $query = "insert into spaces (...". Vary the query to make it simpler. That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just call `mysqli_query` as you normally would, but instead of the query to run you can put in your variable. Note, however, that you can greatly simplify your code:

```
$keys = array_map(function($a) {return "`".$a."`";},array_keys($newrow));
$values = array_map(function($a) {return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."'";},array_values($newrow));
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO spaces (".implode(",",$keys).") values (".implode(",",$values).")");
```